Ускорение процесса обрабооки видео ffmpeg
пишу скрипт конвертирования записей с камер за сутки в один таймлапс длинной в минуту. Использую moviepy. Проблема в том, что процесс записи нового файла очень долгий, более 30 минут. Поигрался с настройками и добился ~15 минут. Но все равно много. Как еще можно ускорить процесс? Может есть какие-то нейронки, которые можно прикрутить? Или есть смылс в облако уйти с vps?
